# Ionic CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while starting new project

Tags: ionic-framework, project

I am new to Ionic I am getting below error when I am creating any new project. 
Could any one help me to fix this issue?

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1240acccf781 <JS Object>
    1: build [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/chalk/index.js:118] [pc=0x185922bbdfc] (this=0x1883445b3691 <JS Function Chalk.chalk.template (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1883445b3199)>,_styles=0x36dd597b5061 <JS Array[1]>,key=0x1240acc57f81 <String[4]: bold>)
    2: _onTimeout [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/utils/task.js:~111] [pc=0x18592337f60] (thi...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [ionic]
 2: 0x109f0ac [ionic]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [ionic]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [ionic]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewTransitionArray(int) [ionic]
 6: v8::internal::TransitionArray::Insert(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) [ionic]
 7: v8::internal::Map::CopyReplaceDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::DescriptorArray>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::LayoutDescriptor>, v8::internal::TransitionFlag, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Name>, char const*, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) [ionic]
 8: v8::internal::Map::CopyAddDescriptor(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Descriptor*, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [ionic]
 9: v8::internal::Map::CopyWithField(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FieldType>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Representation, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [ionic]
10: v8::internal::Map::TransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [ionic]
11: v8::internal::LookupIterator::PrepareTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [ionic]
12: v8::internal::StoreIC::LookupForWrite(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [ionic]
13: v8::internal::StoreIC::UpdateCaches(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [ionic]
14: v8::internal::StoreIC::Store(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [ionic]
15: v8::internal::Runtime_StoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ionic]
16: 0x185921092a7
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following command:

```
$node --max-old-space-size=4096 /usr/local/bin/ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Comment: Worked for me ! Thanks @biranchi