# "CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed" error while building Ionic for Android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic to build for Android and I am always getting this error:

[image: ionic error]

I have this from `ionic info`:

[image: ionic info]

Make no mistake, I have browsed the whole internet finding solutions but I am not successful.
I have seen and read the following:

- [Ionic CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while starting new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188905/ionic-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-whil)
- [Ionic3 android build command not working - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546886/ionic3-android-build-command-not-working-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allo?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Ionic3 - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic3-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-memory/107496)

I also observed that I have this unique error compared to the others:

```
Security context: 000001F502E3FA99 <JS Object>     
    1: createLiteral [..]    
    2: typeToTypeNodeHelper(aka typeToTypeNodeHelper) [..]
```

I have been stuck for over 2 days on this and I really need help and guidance on this.

Here is my package.json content:

```js
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
        "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/twitter-connect": "^4.5.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
        "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-browser": "~5.0.3",
        "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "firebase": "^4.12.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jssha": "^1.6.2",
        "moment": "^2.20.1",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.5",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "twitter-connect-plugin": "git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
        "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.5.7",
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.8",
        "@types/jssha": "0.0.29",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "twitter-connect-plugin": {
                "FABRIC_KEY": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                "TWITTER_KEY": "YYYYYYYYY",
                "TWITTER_SECRET": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "ios",
            "browser",
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

Edit:
I updated my npm as suggested by @Suraj Rao, and I have version 6.0.0 as the current version, then i tried building again and i got this [new related error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxPAM.png)

Comment: Try updating npm .. it looks like a really old version

Comment: ok. let me try that

Comment: After updating to npm to 6.0.0, i got this Security context: 00000015F5F3FA99 <JS Object>
    1: isReadonlySymbol(aka isReadonlySymbol) [C:\Users\user\Downloads\nma\nma\l
atest-NMA-APP\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescri
pt\lib\typescript.js:~41059] [pc=000003C62BFCE163] (this=00000015F5F04241 <undef
ined>,symbol=00000064231D8671 <a SymbolObject with map 000003DF3944C3A1>)
    2: createTypeNodesFromResolvedType(aka createTypeNodesFromResolvedType) [C:\
U...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memo
ry

Comment: hmm please [edit] your post to add further information. People will find it difficult to discern from the comment format

Comment: I have done that

Comment: maybe you need to update node as well current LTS is 8.x and latest is 9.x yours seem to be 6.11..

Comment: ok let me do that

Comment: @Suraj Rao Even after updating node to 8.11.1, still not result

Comment: The below solution worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852018

Answer (score 1):

You can try these steps this might help you!

First of all try `npm install` And follow either one of the following approach...

1. add this to the package.json scripts

   `"ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",`
2. run the command:

   `npm run ionic:build --prod`
3. run the commands:

   `cordova build android --release
   cordova build ios --release`

***OR alternatively***

Modify:

```
node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts.cmd
```

By adding:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=4096  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
)
```

And then run `ionic build android --prod`

Source [Click here!](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1036)

***Update:***

I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong but i can understand there is huge file or memory usage which is exceeding the limit.

Try this,

`node --max-old-space-size=8192 --optimize-for-size --max-executable-size=8192  --max_old_space_size=8192 --optimize_for_size --max_executable_size=8192 node_modules/karma/bin/karma start --single-run --max_new_space_size=8192   --prod --aot`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Probably you just clear your cache of windows, Press `Windows + R` and clear the following folders `temp`, `%temp%`, `prefetch`, and `recent`. After clearing this Restart Your Machine. And Run your command prompt as admin to compile the build.

Comment: Please look in to my comment and Updated answer!

Comment: I am still not making any head way. Still stuck on this error

Comment: Did you try to build other apps? I think that your project produces some huge file content/code. Which is causing this issue. But i'm not exactly sure. Try to build other apps and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I observed that some of the problems were dependency incompatibility (some dependencies needed a particular version to work), but most especially **--prod** in ionic cordova build syntax. This build option is a nightmare of sort. Mine stayed more than 7 hours without terminating. Without this option, it means you are building with angular compiler when you need AOT. After much browsing and reading I was able to build without --prod, but still using AOT via this command  **ionic cordova run android --aot true --environmen
t prod --output-hashing all --sourcemaps false --extract-css true --named-chunks
 false --build-optimizer true**  check it [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1243). Though not sure if its the right thing to do, but I got the result i wanted.